# Built-in iSight camera in MacBook Pro stops working in Skype

Tags: macbook-pro, skype, webcam

I'm using macbook pro mid 2009. Everything is working good but my camera. The problem is camera stops working after 1-2 minutes in skype chat. And during the conversation I can't close my camera because camera icon is not working. Is that problem about camera or skype? And how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen problems like this before with Skype and I'm pretty sure there's nothing you can do about it.  Make sure you're not running any other apps that are using the camera and that you've got the latest version of Skype installed.  I've found that sometimes going into the Skype preferences and clicking on the "Audio/Video" icon can "free" it up.